# Calculator with html, css and js. I have no idea what's wrong

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

Followed a youtube tutorial, reviewed the code countless times and I don't know what's wrong. The calculator sometimes works, other times doesnt. Some buttons (+, -, x, ⁄) dont work. Here's the entire code cause I have no ideia where the problem might be. I started with html, css and then js, I think the problem must be in the js part

```js
let runningTotal = 0;
let buffer = 0;
let previousOperator;

const screen = document.querySelector('.screen');

function buttonClick(value){
    if (isNaN(value)){
        handleSymbol(value);       
    }else{
        handleNumber(value);
    }
    screen.innerText = buffer;
}

function handleSymbol(symbol){
    switch(symbol){
        case "C":
            buffer = '0';
            runningTotal = 0;
            break;
        case '=':
            if(previousOperator === null){
                return
            }
            flushOperation (parseInt(buffer));
            previousOperator = null;
            buffer = runningTotal;
            runningTotal = 0;
            break
        case '←':
            if(buffer.length === 1){
                buffer = '0';
            }else{
                buffer = buffer.substring(0, buffer.length - 1);
            }
            break;
        case '+':
        case '−':
        case '×':
        case '÷':
            handleMath(symbol);
            break;
    }
}

function handleMath(symbol){
    if(buffer === '0'){
        return;
    }

    const intBuffer = parseInt(buffer);

    if(runningTotal === '0'){
        runningTotal = intBuffer
    }else{
        flushOperation(intBuffer);
    }
    previousOperator = symbol;
    buffer = '0';
}

function flushOperation(intBuffer){
    if(previousOperator === '+'){
        runningTotal += intBuffer;
    }else if(previousOperator === '−'){
        runningTotal -= intBuffer;
    }else if(previousOperator === '×'){
        runningTotal *= intBuffer;
    }else if(previousOperator === '÷'){
        runningTotal /= intBuffer;
    }
}

function handleNumber(numberString){
    if(buffer === '0'){
        buffer = numberString;
    }else{
        buffer += numberString;
    }
}

function init(){
    document.querySelector('.calc-buttons').addEventListener('click', function(event){
        buttonClick(event.target.innerText);
 })
}

init();
```

```css
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(320deg, #eb92be, #ffef78, #63c9b4);
    display: flex;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    font-display: swap;
    height: inherit;
    justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper{
   backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
   -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(55.5px);
   border-radius: 16px; 
   box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.1);
   color: #232323;
   backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
   -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
   background: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.30);
   border: 1px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.34);
   flex-basis: 400px;
   height: 540px;
   padding: 20px 35px;
}
.screen{
    backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    background:rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.75);
    border: 1px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.01);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.1);
    color: #232323;
    font-size: 35px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 326px;
}  

.calc-button-row{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 5% 0;
}

.calc-button{
    backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    background: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.75);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.1);
    color: #232323;
    flex-basis: 20%;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 65px;
}

.calc-button:last-child{
    backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    background: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.75);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.1);
    color: #fff;
    background: #d72880;
}
.calc-button:last-child:hover{
    background-color: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}

.calc-button:hover{
    background-color: inherit;

}

.calc-button:active{
    background-color: #ffef78;
}

.double{
    flex-basis: 47%;
}

.triple{
    flex-basis: 73%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <section class="screen">
        0
      </section>

      <section class="calc-buttons">
        <div class="calc-button-row">
            <button class="calc-button double">
              C
            </button>
            <button class="calc-button">
              &larr;
            </button>
            <button class="calc-button">
              &divide;
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="calc-button-row">
            <button class="calc-button">
              7
            </button>
            <button class="calc-button">
              8
            </button>
            <button class="calc-button">
              9
            </button>
            <button class="calc-button">
              &times;
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="calc-button-row">
            <button class="calc-button">
              4
            </button>
            <button class="calc-button">
              5
            </button>
            <button class="calc-button">
              6
            </button>
            <button class="calc-button">
              &minus;
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="calc-button-row">
              <button class="calc-button">
                1
              </button>
              <button class="calc-button">
                2
              </button>
              <button class="calc-button">
                3
              </button>
              <button class="calc-button">
                &plus;
              </button>
        </div>

        <div class="calc-button-row">
              <button class="calc-button triple">
                0
              </button>
              <button class="calc-button">
                &equals;
              </button>
              
            </div>
      </section>
    </div>


  <script src="scrip.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I've reviewed the code word by word, can't find the problem

Comment: _what_ doesn't work specifically?

Comment: I have tried the snippet and it really does not work. Due to the length of the code, it is difficult to say where the problem is. You need to simplify your code to better find the problem. I advise you to simplify your application to only addition and test that.

Comment: @AndyHolmes sometimes the multiplication, addition, subtraction and division don't work, other times do. When I open up the webpage of the calculator when I click the numbers they show up dialled on the console but the multiplication, addition, subtraction and division sometimes don't. What's really weird is that it's not even the same problem, cause sometimes ir does work. I just did 8 x 4 and it showed 32, I did it again and it showed 0. I truly have no idea, do you think you can help? It'd be very appreciated

Comment: @JakubHolan that's a great suggestion, i will try to simplify it

Comment: @IanKemp i know that, but I'm just starting out in programming and i tried this for hours by myself without solving it. This is sort of a last resort thing, I'm sorry if it made you upset

Comment: @Melissa there are many forums on the internet where people new to programming can get the kind of assistance they desire. Stack Overflow is specifically not intended to be one of these.

Comment: @Melissa: Also, since you are a beginner, I would advise you to make small steps when programming and rigorously test each step before you go to the another. In this example it could be, e.g.: create HTML code, create CSS code, create JS function for addition, create JS function for subtraction, etc. If you make small steps, it's much easier to identify where exactly problem occurs. If you write one long code and only then test it, it can be very difficult to identify the problems. When you find the specific problem, you can then ask here on Stack for help with the specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issues I found:

1. Sometimes buffer is number, sometimes - string. So in line:

`buffer = buffer.substring(0, buffer.length - 1);`

you have an Uncaught TypeError, so try always convert it to a string:

`buffer = buffer.toString().substring(0, buffer.length - 1);`

2. You are trying to check that runningTotal equals string '0', but it is a number.

`if (runningTotal === 0)`

You need to carefully check the types of all variables because now it's a bit messy.